# why mongoose findOne returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I don't know why this mongoose `findOne` always returning `null`, when I hit the api endpoint via postman.

```
exports.updateUserPassword = async(req,res) =>{
   const user = await User.findOne({
        resetPasswordExpires:{ $gt:Date.now() },
        resetPasswordToken:req.params.token

    })
    if(!user){
        res.json({"msg":"Password is invalid or has been expired"})
    }
}
```

on the terminal when I console.log, then I get this

```
{
    _id: 5e4553309d0e232a60gc8b6a,
    userName: 'Dan_rey',
    userType: 'Group',
    email: 'dan123@gmail.com',
    password: '$2b$10$lq6BYYckKkOtY.as.EILMe7a.njPyBrHauxMlFfianxmSwdmiAT12',
    date: 2019-12-29T19:49:04.608Z,
    __v: 0,
    resetPasswordExpires: 2019-12-30T19:04:05.874Z,
    resetPasswordToken: '65bc534656b321907c5af968b13d0a44f41de73b'
  }
```

but I want only these two's, when I use mongoose findOne
  1) resetPasswordExpires,
  2) resetPasswordToken

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely reason is there are no matching records in the db.

Comment: but if I use mongoose Find() command, then it will return all the documents with: resetPasswordToken and resetPasswordExpires @SergioTulentsev

Comment: can you add the document which is supposed to be find? and also the req.params.token value

Comment: yeah sure @SuleymanSah

Comment: We need to see the document in json format

Comment: now look it @SuleymanSah

Comment: @KuldeepSharma What value do you send in req.params.token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205097/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-kuldeep-sharma).

Comment: Ok come on chat @SuleymanSah

Comment: "but if I use mongoose Find()" - just `Find`, with empty search criteria? Of course it will return all documents, because there's no filter now.

Comment: check this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#onerror

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because Date.now() return an epoch format for date but the format that you are storing is different. Mongo is unable to find any document with that condition and hence it returns zero results.
For getting the date in ISO format, use **new Date()** instead of **Date.now()**.

For validating this - 
You can insert the below document in mongodb as insertOne of following body -

```
db.collection_name.insertOne({
    date_format_1: Date.now(),
    date_format_2: new Date()
})
```

Follow the link below for more details -
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/